# "File-name" has been damaged : Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, isolatedstorage, launcher

[image]

I am launching document from isolated storage, when I debug on next code, previous stream gets closed and getting this exception.

```
"File-Name" has been damaged and can't be opened.
```

See my code below:

```
 using (IsolatedStorageFile storageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
 {
     using (stream = storageFile.OpenFile("Document.docx", FileMode.Create))
     {
        await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
     }               
 }

StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile pdffile = await local.GetFileAsync("Document.docx");

await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdffile);
```

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: @DecadeMoon Thank you brother for yuour response, but now I am getting new  error. "FILE_NAME" has been damaged and can't be opened" please help me, how to solve it?

Comment: @DecadeMoon I am trying to launch office files and pdf files.

Comment: Which line of code is causing the first error and which one causes the second one?

Comment: @xmashallax Thank you brother for yuour response, but now I am getting new error. "FILE_NAME" has been damaged and can't be opened" please help me, how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

1) Make Sure If you are Downloading file from the URI than you should use  WebClient instead of HttpWebRequest
2) Make sure you paas the correct URI

Comment: I have done it using Background Downloader. I was trying to launch it before completely download,so it was corrupting. Now I solved it. Wanna see code?? @Deepak